# bash "catch block" is not catching bad subshell

Tags: bash, shell-script, jq, subshell

So I have this:

```
  (
        set -eo pipefail;
         {
          set -eo pipefail;
        file_path="$(echo "$i" | jq -r '.file_path')"

         if [[ -n "$file_path" ]]; then
              echo "$i" > "$file_path";
          fi
        } || {
           # never seems to reach here
           echo "!!! json parse error: 'xxxx'";
        }
     )
```

I would expected this in my terminal:

```
!!! json parse error: 'xxxx'
```

But I keep getting this `jq` error in my terminal:

```
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 0
```

not sure why the "catch block" that normally works for me isn't working here

Comment: Can you explain why you expected that line to be reached? Is it that you thought the pipefail would do this? Did you expect the whole script to exit because of the `set -e`? I am really having trouble understanding why you would expect to see that message from that code.

Answer (score 1):

The `pipefail` shell option in `bash` causes the exit status of a pipeline to be that of the right-most command with a non-zero exit status (or zero if all commands exit successfully).  In your case, the only pipeline you have is an `echo`+`jq` pipeline, and `echo` is unlikely to fail, rendering the `pipefail` option superfluous.

The `errexit` (`set -e`) shell option causes the shell to terminate at the first command that returns a non-zero exit status, *unless* the command is part of an AND-OR list, such as the one in your code.

The only way to provoke the `!!! json parse error: 'xxxx'` output from your code would by `if` compound command returning a non-zero exit status, which it would do if the shell could not write to the file in `$file_path`.

Personally, I would stay clear of both these shell options unless you come across a case where they are absolutely needed (I still haven't seen one of those cases in my own shell scripts, ever).

---

You seem to want to write your JSON document to a file (given by the output of `jq`) if the parsing generates some non-empty value and to output an error message if the parsing fails.

Determining whether parsing went well is probably easiest done by using the exit status from `jq` directly in an `if` statement.

Here, we additionally capture the error output from `jq` and use that in our own error reporting:

```bash
if filepath=$( jq -r '.file_path' <<<"$json_document" 2>&1 )
then
    # Parsing went ok.
    if [ -n "$filepath" ]; then
        # "$filepath" is non-empty.
        printf '%s\n' "$json_document" >"$filepath"
    fi
else
    # Parsing failed.
    printf 'ERROR: "%s"\n' "$filepath" >&2
fi
```

But honestly, I would just let `jq` do its own error reporting and not get involved with that at all, which simplifies the code:

```bash
if filepath=$( jq -r '.file_path' <<<"$json_document" ) && [ -n "$filepath" ]
then
    # Parsing went ok, and "$filepath" is non-empty.
    printf '%s\n' "$json_document" >"$filepath"
fi
```

Or, let `jq` tell us the value was empty, which gets rid of the `-n` test:

```bash
if filepath=$( jq -r -e '.file_path' <<<"$json_document" )
then
    # Parsing went ok, and "$filepath" is non-empty (and not null or false).
    printf '%s\n' "$json_document" >"$filepath"
fi
```

With `-e`, `jq` will return a non-zero exit status on errors (as usual), but also if the final expression results in an empty result, `null`, or `false`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand why you would expect to see that message. You are testing the exit code of a group of commands, which means you are testing the exit code of the last command in the group. In your case, the last command is the `if` or, if the `if` is true, the `echo`:

```
  if [[ -n "$file_path" ]]; then
    echo is n
  fi
```

Since this is the last command to run, *that* is what your `|| echo "!!! json parse error: 'xxxx'"` tests against, and since both the `if` and the `echo` if executed will return true, you never go into your "catch block".

If you expected this to be executed because of the `pipefail` option, that won't work since this isn't a pipe:

```
$ { false | true; } || echo FAILED
$ set -o pipefail 
$ { false | true; } || echo FAILED
FAILED
```

But if I now add another non-failing command after the pipe:

```
 $ { false | true; true;} || echo FAILED
 $
```

That's what you have in your script.